# How convert Array To List but in Uppercase?

Tags: coldfusion, arraylist

Coldfusion 8 version here.
Here is a snipset of my code:

```
<cfset ColumnNames  = structKeyArray(ApiData[1])>           
<cfdump var="#ColumnNames#"><!--- lowercase names --->              
<cfdump var="#ArrayToList(ColumnNames,",")#"> <!--- need each name in Array in UPPERCASE --->
```

uCase(ColumnNames) wont work. Do I have to loop it through each item and use uCase?

Thank you

Comment: What if you applied ucase to the last cfdump?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or even just turn it into a list first using `structKeyList()`, which you can call `uCase()` on.

```
<cfset ColumnNames  = uCase(structKeyList(ApiData[1]))>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is ugly, but you could do:

```
listToArray( UCase( structKeyList( ApiData[ 1 ] ) ) )
```